# How to call servlet from html

Tags: servlets

I am new in the servlet programming, so I want to ask how to call servlet from a html file.Basically I am using eclipse oxygen 3.0 for it, and already tried everything but did't success to call servlet from html.I also mention servlet in web.xml file as below

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ShowParameters</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>coreservlets.ShowParameters</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ShowParameters</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/ShowParameters</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am using coreservlets as a package.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1) by using anchor tag:

`<a href='ShowParameters?name=myname'> some url </a>`

2) by using below form:

```
<form action="ShowParameters" method="post">
   Name: <input  maxlength="100" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder=""  />
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL.  I am getting this error.

Comment: In URL process you do not specify request type and by default request type will be GET.. Add a method doGet() in your servlet like doPost()